# Sort inside of a query or filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am using elasticsearch.net client. I query something with pagination. But it returns documents according to sorting criteria not query criteria.It is like it ignores the query just works with sorting. Thing is I want to sort all documents then process the query. I think if I can use ***sort*** inside of a query that'll solve the problem.Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Here is code piece.

```
    ISearchResponse<Product> response = _elasticClient
                .Search<Product>(p => p
                    .From(request.Pagination.PageIndex - 1)
                    .Size(request.Pagination.ItemCount)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(m => m.Term(genderTerm => genderTerm.ProductGenderTypeList, request.BoutiqueFilter.GenderTypeList ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()))
                            .Should(s => s
                                .Match(m2 => m2
                                    .OnField(on => on.ProductGenderType)
                                    .Query((request.BoutiqueFilter.SortGender == SortGender.None ? String.Empty : ((int)request.BoutiqueFilter.SortGender).ToString()))
                                    .Operator(Operator.And)))))
                    .Sort(sort => request.BoutiqueFilter.SortByPrice == SortByPrice.None
                    ? sort.OnField(onf => onf.Sequence).Ascending()
                    : request.BoutiqueFilter.SortByPrice == SortByPrice.Ascending
                        ? sort.OnField(onf => onf.Price).Ascending()
                        : sort.OnField(onf => onf.Price).Descending()));
```